# Side input data gets updated very late - Python Apache Beam

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm building a pipeline with dynamic configuration data that gets updated whenever is triggered.

There are 5 PubSub topics, 1 topic is for the IoT data, the other 4 are for the configurations that will be used to transform the IoT data.

The configuration is kept in Cloud Firestore documents. When each document gets updated, Cloud Function will read and send the updated configuration 1 of the 4 PubSub subscriptions.

When the configuration gets updated, **the new side input data gets mixed in and doesn't really replace by the new side input data.**
And I've waited for at least 30 mins, the old side input is still present.
I'm using *Dataflow Runner V2*

```
p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)

class Transform(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, configuration):
        ...
        yield output

def run():
    ...
    iot_data = (p
        | 'ReadIotData' >> ReadFromPubSub(SUBSCRIPTION_IOT)

    config_1 = (p
        | 'ReadConfig' >> ReadFromPubSub(SUBSCRIPTION_1)
        | 'WindowUserData' >> beam.WindowInto(
            window.GlobalWindows(),
            trigger=trigger.Repeatedly(trigger.AfterCount(1)),
            accumulation_mode=trigger.AccumulationMode.DISCARDING)
        | 'LoadsUserData' >> beam.Map(lambda x: ('data', x.decode().replace('\\','')))

    config_2 = # same as config_1 with different PubSub subscription
    config_3 = # same as config_1 with different PubSub subscription
    config_4 = # same as config_1 with different PubSub subscription

    output = (iot_data
        | 'transform' >> beam.ParDo(Transform(),
            pvalue.AsDict(config_1),
            pvalue.AsDict(config_2),
            pvalue.AsDict(config_3),
            pvalue.AsDict(config_4))
        | 'Output' >> WriteToPubSub(TOPIC_C)
```

---

**UPDATE**

Adding more workers kind of help the side input update performance. It gets a little quicker in proportion to the workers added. But still not where I want.

Comment: Lets see if I understand it right: the output for config_1 for example has old data and dont get updated when a new messaged is sent to SUBSCRIPTION_1?

Comment: @R.Esteves When a new message is sent to SUBSCRIPTION_1, the _Elements added_ in the diagram is increased, so I think it goes in. But the ParDo just doesn't grab and use the new config_1 instantly, it still process with the old config_1 data. The output to TOPIC_C has mixed of old and new config_1 data.

Comment: Is there some specific reason for you to use a Window in the config_x pipelines? It seems that you dont do any aggregation

Comment: I got the idea from other stackoverflow topic about  _slowly changing lookup cache_. I have also tried running the pipeline without windowing, but the data doesn't get processed all together.